# Why does pip install hang on this URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi

## Background

It's been awhile since I've spent time programming, so I decided to tackle a project on a RaspberryPi.

I am trying to develop a module called `aosong`. I currently have it published on [Github](https://github.com/roder/aosong) and on [Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aosong/0.0.1).  It has a dependency called [quick2wire-api, which is only hosted on Github](https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-python-api).

## Goal

Ultimately my goal is to do `pip install aosong` or have `aosong` in a `requirements.txt` file in an application that I'm building and for it to include the installation of `quick2wire

## Current Status

So when I try to do a pip install, this is what I get

```
(test_aosong)matt@raspberrypi:~/src/aosong$ pip install -v -v -v aosong
Downloading/unpacking aosong
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/aosong/
  URLs to search for versions for aosong:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/aosong/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/aosong/
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/a/aosong/aosong-0.0.1-py3.4.egg#md5=9af74215cbfcfed8e046a4557824ee24 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/aosong/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/aosong/aosong-0.0.1.linux-armv6l.tar.gz#md5=98a957680fd3ed729ba0a51b38b54ece (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/aosong/), version: 0.0.1.linux-armv6l
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/aosong/aosong-0.0.1.tar.gz#md5=d1a76e0044472a782e72adb8e858a264 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/aosong/), version: 0.0.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/aosong/aosong-0.0.1.linux-armv6l.tar.gz#md5=98a957680fd3ed729ba0a51b38b54ece (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/aosong/), version 0.0.1.linux-armv6l is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
  Downloading aosong-0.0.1.tar.gz
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/aosong/aosong-0.0.1.tar.gz#md5=d1a76e0044472a782e72adb8e858a264 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/aosong/)
  Running setup.py (path:/home/matt/.pyenv/versions/test_aosong/build/aosong/setup.py) egg_info for package aosong
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/aosong.egg-info
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/aosong.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/aosong.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/aosong.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info/aosong.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/aosong.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/aosong.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/aosong.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /home/matt/.pyenv/versions/test_aosong/build/aosong has version 0.0.1, which satisfies requirement aosong
Downloading/unpacking quick2wire-api>=0.0.0.2 (from aosong)
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/quick2wire-api/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/quick2wire-api/: 404 Client Error: Not Found
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/quick2wire-api/ when looking for download links for quick2wire-api>=0.0.0.2 (from aosong)
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

## 10 minutes later...

At this point it hangs for a good 10 minutes or more.  After some amount of time passes, then this is the remaining portion:

```
URLs to search for versions for quick2wire-api>=0.0.0.2 (from aosong):
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/quick2wire-api/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/quick2wire-api/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/quick2wire-api/: 404 Client Error: Not Found
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/quick2wire-api/ when looking for download links for quick2wire-api>=0.0.0.2 (from aosong)
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement quick2wire-api>=0.0.0.2 (from aosong)
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /home/matt/.pyenv/versions/test_aosong/build...
No distributions at all found for quick2wire-api>=0.0.0.2 (from aosong)
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/.pyenv/versions/test_aosong/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/matt/.pyenv/versions/test_aosong/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/home/matt/.pyenv/versions/test_aosong/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/home/matt/.pyenv/versions/test_aosong/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for quick2wire-api>=0.0.0.2 (from aosong)
```

## More CONTEXT

### Locally

If I install `pip install -r requirements.txt` from the `asong` module's root, the installation works perfectly.

Additionally, if I install via setup tools, ala `python setup.py install` it also works flawlessly.

### The Environment

```
(test_aosong)matt@raspberrypi:~/src/aosong$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.12.28+ #709 PREEMPT Mon Sep 8 15:28:00 BST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
(test_aosong)matt@raspberrypi:~/src/aosong$ pip list
pip (1.5.6)
pkginfo (1.1)
requests (2.4.1)
setuptools (3.6)
twine (1.3.1)
(test_aosong)matt@raspberrypi:~/src/aosong$ pyenv virtualenvs
  am2315 (created from /home/matt/.pyenv/versions/3.4.1)
* test_aosong (created from /home/matt/.pyenv/versions/3.4.1)
(test_aosong)matt@raspberrypi:~/src/aosong$ pyenv which python
/home/matt/.pyenv/versions/test_aosong/bin/python
(test_aosong)matt@raspberrypi:~/src/aosong$
```

## The Question

Can someone help me understand why `pip install aosong` is not installing `quick2wire-api1` dependency?

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --process-dependency-links aosong
```

Comment: you should explain why this option solves the problem

Comment: why do you need to add the flag? shouldn't it 'just work' ?
edit: probably due to this message "DEPRECATION: Dependency Links processing has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release." on using